# Increase number of results on GET API callin Vue

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, query-string

I am trying to fetch all orders from Woocommerce REST API, but as default I get only 10 orders. As per the API documentation i have tried to use "Per_page=20" . But it was not working, and throwing 401 and 400 bad requests error. Am i making wrong in url?
Below is my Vue script.

```js
methods: {
  refreshData () {
    axios.get('https://mysite/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?per_page=20/consumer_key=key&consumer_secret=key')
```

Comment: Is that `/` after `per_page=20` meant to be an `&` instead?

Comment: yeah, that worked. Thanks a lot...